# Ng-options - iterate in multiple properties of a single object

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

Hi Can any one let me know how can I make ng-options to select from multiple collections based up on a condition.

```
 <select class="form-control" data-ng-model="model1" data-ng-options="tmp.Name as tmp.Name for tmp in Temp.Names.FiltereDepartments"><option value="">Select Value</option></select>
```

In the above code instead of FiltereDepartments, I want to change the value of this to property based up on a condition, is this possible to achieve using ng-class or which one can I use with in select clause to check for conditions and change the collection name accordingly.

Comment: You'll probably have to make your `ng-options` more generic and change the model out in your controller instead of trying to do it in the view. Or have multiple `<select>` elements and use `ng-if` to determine which one should be used, but that could get messy if you have lots of possible collections that you want to use in your `<select>`.

Comment: @Lex Is there any example on the same on how to makes changes on the model. I tried to search but no luck. And I do not have too many collections just two of them but ng-if is not shown with the version am using.

Comment: I'm not aware of any examples, but the basic idea would be to have `ng-options="item.Name as item.Name for item in genericCollection"` and in your controller you can change what you load into `genericCollection` as necessary. You'd also have to have a generic object for `ng-model` and do whatever you need to with the selected option. `ng-show` would be an alternative to `ng-if`.